# How to Connect Github Repository (as a source of command) to a mysql-server?

Tags: mysql, github, devops

Is there any option to link Github Repository with a mysql server ?

I have a plan to store all sql queries in gitHub repository. Then I want to run the sql queries once it is uploaded or pushed on to the repository.

I have tried to find any references but I can not find one.

I want to create/run the query automatically whenever I put a new sql file.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not use some intermediate server for that and GitHub hooks?

Comment: Correct. but my environment does not have domain name. It's localhost. Do you have any option related this?